# Misplaced margin notes with scrlayer-notecolumn inside a scrbook

Tags: scrbook, scrlayer-notecolumn

Margin notes added with `scrlayer-notecolumn`'s `\makenote` are misplaced. Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\title{A book}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello, world!\makenote{A margin note.}

\end{document}
```

The output pdf file contains two pages. The margin note appears on the title page instead of on the page where the text is located.

[image: A misplaced margin note]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't test now, but I believe `scrlayer-notecolumn` works (better? best? only?) when also `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded.

Comment: @campa: Yes, this solved the problem. Thanks! Will you write an answer?

Comment: yes, without it the value of the page is one off. You could make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've reported the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ulrike Fischer's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604966/misplaced-margin-notes-with-scrlayer-notecolumn-inside-a-scrbook#comment1517138_604966), this is a bug in the `scrlayer-notecolumn` package. Per campa's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604966/misplaced-margin-notes-with-scrlayer-notecolumn-inside-a-scrbook#comment1517126_604966), it can be worked around by loading `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn}
```

I've tested this workaround, and it indeed works.